# Generating AMD modules with webpack and CommonsChunkPlugin

Tags: webpack, amd

I am developing multiple plugins to a system that loads these plugins as AMD modules (with requirejs). Plugins are written as ES6 modules and packed with webpack (output.libraryTarget = 'amd'). Everything works as expected so far.

But plugins share quite a lot of common code that is bundled into every entry. I tried to use `CommonsChunkPlugin` webpack plugin but initial chunk contains code that is not AMD module. However other entry points relaying on common chuck are still generated correctly. Also [documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#multiple-entry-chunks) says that it is not good idea to have multiple initial chunks (with JSONp runtime) on one page - there is possibility that another plugin author would use same approach.

Is there a way to optimize this use case in AMD compatible manner?
It seems to me as a bug in `CommonsChunkPlugin` that the initial entry is not AMD (but still its code is not safe to be loaded in plugin env)... Is there a configuration I am missing?

Comment: Same problem here. Seems that having chunks for whatever reason and producing an amd library is incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that understand you correctly. But if you want to build your bundle as AMD module, than you must config it as a [library](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-library):

```
...
output: {
    ...
    library: true,
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
},
```

Comment: So you maybe needed to configure libraryTarget parameter according to your exporting way: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-librarytarget

Comment: That work correctly. But I want to use [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin) and the output of common chunks is not AMD.

Comment: I have multiple entry points and I know that those entry points share 90% of code (modules). Therefore I want to use CommonsChunksPlugin to generate new AMD module with all the common modules.

Comment: Yeah, but webpack handling them automatically. So I don't get it. You have entry point (e.g. main.js) and common chunks. You use your main.js and main.js loads all of your common chunks. Where you want to use AMD?

Comment: I need to provide plugin to external system as AMD module(s) that would be loaded by requirejs. The problem is that {common chunks}.js uses global function. It would crash badly if anybody else would use the same way to create plugin - webpack + common chunks.